# Как правильно хранить данные в формате "дата" в SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Как правильно или как обычно хранят данные в формате "дата" в SQL ? Вот например на игровом сервере онлайн игры,  хранят дату в формате String, то есть обычную строку с датой туда вписывают. Нормально ли это считается, так хранить дату?

формат:

```
 день | месяц | год  
 и
 день | месяц | год | часы | минуты | секунды
```

Comment: Есть тип данных DATETIME, в том числе в SQLite. Я пока не встречался с ситуациями, где вместо него надо что-то свое изобретать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

152 bit требуется для хранения даты в виде строки "12/14/2015 11:21:25".
64 bit требуется для хранения этой же даты в виде числа 635856888850000000. 
 
чтобы получить интервал между датами, надо просто получить разницу между числами, а в случае использования строк их надо предварительно парсить.

в SQL есть специальный тип для даты и времени. 
например, в T-SQL их несколько - см. [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms186724(v=sql.120).aspx)